# Counting the number of files in a directory using C

Tags: c, linux, file

How can I count the number of files in a directory using C on linux platform.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

No guarantee that this code compiles, and it's really only compatible with Linux and the BSDs:

```
#include <dirent.h>

...

int file_count = 0;
DIR * dirp;
struct dirent * entry;

dirp = opendir("path"); /* There should be error handling after this */
while ((entry = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
    if (entry->d_type == DT_REG) { /* If the entry is a regular file */
         file_count++;
    }
}
closedir(dirp);
```

Comment: If you want to process files in subdirectories, you can recurse when you encounter a directory entry. Make sure to exclude "." and ".." if you do this.

Comment: Good job on catching the dirent include.

Comment: Yes, they are POSIX functions.

Comment: POSIX specifies only d_ino and d_name as members of the dirent-structure.  This code tests for d_type, which is platform-specific.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering why you must loop through and why there's no function to just get how many files are in a directory in constant time, I found this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/17/9426787.aspx

Comment: @sudo given that the answer is really old and the article has been deleted, here's a link of the same article on the WayBack Machine (2019-02-08): https://web.archive.org/web/20190208213958/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090217-00/?p=19123/

Answer (score 6):

See [`readdir`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/readdir.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to include subdirectories as well, you can use this function that I'm using in some of my code. You should probably modify it to include some more error checking and support different directory separators.

```
int countfiles(char *path) {
    DIR *dir_ptr = NULL;
    struct dirent *direntp;
    char *npath;
    if (!path) return 0;
    if( (dir_ptr = opendir(path)) == NULL ) return 0;

    int count=0;
    while( (direntp = readdir(dir_ptr)))
    {
        if (strcmp(direntp->d_name,".")==0 ||
            strcmp(direntp->d_name,"..")==0) continue;
        switch (direntp->d_type) {
            case DT_REG:
                ++count;
                break;
            case DT_DIR:            
                npath=malloc(strlen(path)+strlen(direntp->d_name)+2);
                sprintf(npath,"%s/%s",path, direntp->d_name);
                count += countfiles(npath);
                free(npath);
                break;
        }
    }
    closedir(dir_ptr);
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about current directory `.` and the  parent directory`..` like this ones:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 michi michi      4096 Dec 21 15:54 .
drwx------ 30 michi michi     12288 Jan  3 10:23 ..
```

You can do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void){
    size_t count = 0;
    struct dirent *res;
    struct stat sb;
    const char *path = "/home/michi/";

    if (stat(path, &sb) == 0 && S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)){
        DIR *folder = opendir ( path );

        if (access ( path, F_OK ) != -1 ){
            if ( folder ){
                while ( ( res = readdir ( folder ) ) ){
                    if ( strcmp( res->d_name, "." ) && strcmp( res->d_name, ".." ) ){
                        printf("%zu) - %s\n", count + 1, res->d_name);
                        count++;
                    }
                }

                closedir ( folder );
            }else{
                perror ( "Could not open the directory" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

    }else{
        printf("The %s it cannot be opened or is not a directory\n", path);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf( "\n\tFound %zu Files\n", count );
}
```

Output:

```
1) - .gnome2
2) - .linuxmint
3) - .xsession-errors
4) - .nano
5) - .kde
6) - .xsession-errors.old
7) - .gnome2_private
8) - Public
9) - .gconf
10) - .bashrc
11) - .macromedia
12) - .thunderbird
13) - Pictures
14) - .profile
15) - .cinnamon
16) - .pki
17) - Compile
18) - Desktop
19) - .Private
20) - .cache
21) - .Xauthority
22) - .ICEauthority
23) - VirtualBox VMs
24) - .bash_history
25) - .mozilla
26) - .local
27) - .config
28) - .codeblocks
29) - Documents
30) - .bash_logout
31) - Videos
32) - Templates
33) - Downloads
34) - .adobe
35) - .gphoto
36) - Music
37) - .dbus
38) - .ecryptfs
39) - .sudo_as_admin_successful
40) - .gnome

    Found 40 Files
```

Comment: Not the downvoter but why would you answer a question that's been asked almost 9 years ago with accepted answer? Is your answer significantly better? Did something change resulting in invalidating the accepted answer?

Comment: @Fureeish Because SO is not dedicated only to one particular Question/Answer. If there is some more information you can provide to the Question should be a SO answer. This Answer it is here to extend the Accepted one.

Comment: @Fureeish Ok I see your point. I added more code (stat and acccess) to make the answer different from the Accepted one.