# Find the number of files in a directory

Tags: linux, file, shell, directory, counting

Is there any method in Linux to calculate the number of files in a directory (that is, immediate children) in O(1) (independently of the number of files) without having to list the directory first? If not O(1), is there a reasonably efficient way?

I'm searching for an alternative to `ls | wc -l`.

Comment: What part about `ls| wc -l` isn't O(1)?

Comment: ls | wc -l will cause ls to do an opendir(), readdir() and probably a stat() on all the files. This will generally be at least O(n).

Comment: @halfdan: ls outputs all files, so it's O(n)

Comment: Yeah correct, my fault. I was thinking of O(1) and O(n) to be same, although I should know it better.

Comment: Can't you just use shell globbing?

Comment: Related: I wrote some code and did some testing for a similar question in [here: _the fastest way to count files in directory_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210553/4162356)

Comment: [Counting the number of files in a directory using C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1121383/608639).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

readdir is not as expensive as you may think. The knack is avoid stat'ing each file, and (optionally) sorting the output of ls.

`/bin/ls -1U | wc -l`

avoids aliases in your shell, doesn't sort the output, and lists 1 file-per-line (not strictly necessary when piping the output into wc).

The original question can be rephrased as "does the data structure of a directory store a count of the number of entries?", to which the answer is no. There isn't a more efficient way of counting files than readdir(2)/getdents(2).

Comment: To avoid aliases, you can also say `\ls`. Check [\curl … | bash … what's the slash for?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15951871/1983854)

Comment: Today I learned about the `-1` option. So useful for scripting to purge that `total 0` line, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

One can get the number of subdirectories of a given directory without traversing the whole list by stat'ing (stat(1) or stat(2)) the given directory and observing the number of links to that directory.  A given directory with N child directories will have a link count of N+2, one link for the ".." entry of each subdirectory, plus two for the "." and ".." entries of the given directory.

However one cannot get the number of all files (whether regular files or subdirectories) without traversing the whole list -- that is correct.

The "/bin/ls -1U" command will not get all entries however.  It will get *only* those directory entries that do not start with the dot (.) character.  For example, it would not count the ".profile" file found in many login $HOME directories.

One can use either the "/bin/ls -f" command or the "/bin/ls -Ua" command to avoid the sort and get all entries.

Perhaps unfortunately for your purposes, either the "/bin/ls -f" command or the "/bin/ls -Ua" command will also count the "." and ".." entries that are in each directory.  You will have to subtract 2 from the count to avoid counting these two entries, such as in the following:

```
expr `/bin/ls -f | wc -l` - 2     # Those are back ticks, not single quotes.
```

The --format=single-column (-1) option is not necessary on the "/bin/ls -Ua" command when piping the "ls" output, as in to "wc" in this case.  The "ls" command will automatically write its output in a single column if the output is not a terminal.

Comment: Agreed that `ls -f` is better than `ls -1U` (I think `-f` is meant for such piping), but I wish `ls` had an option to terminate each filename with a NUL character instead of a newline.

Comment: on Linux: `-b, --escape print C-style escapes for nongraphic characters`; that will print embedded newlines as `\n`.

Answer (score 3):

The `-U` option for `ls` is not in POSIX, and in OS X's `ls` it has a different meaning from GNU `ls`, which is that it makes `-t` and `-l` use creation times instead of modification times. `-f` is in POSIX as an XSI extension. The manual of GNU `ls` describes `-f` as `do not sort, enable -aU, disable -ls --color` and `-U` as `do not sort; list entries in directory order`.

POSIX describes `-f` like this:

> Force each argument to be interpreted as a directory and list the name found in each slot. This option shall turn off `-l`, `-t`, `-s`, and `-r`, and shall turn on `-a`; the order is the order in which entries appear in the directory.

Commands like `ls|wc -l` give the wrong result when filenames contain newlines.

In zsh you can do something like this:

```
a=(*(DN));echo ${#a}
```

`D` (`glob_dots`) includes files whose name starts with a period and `N` (`null_glob`) causes the command to not result in an error in an empty directory.

Or the same in bash:

```
shopt -s dotglob nullglob;a=(*);echo ${#a[@]}
```

If `IFS` contains ASCII digits, add double quotes around `${#a[@]}`. Add `shopt -u failglob` to ensure that `failglob` is unset.

A portable option is to use `find`:

```
find . ! -name . -prune|grep -c /
```

`grep -c /` can be replaced with `wc -l` if filenames do not contain newlines. `! -name . -prune` is a portable alternative to `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`.

Or here's another alternative that does not usually include files whose name starts with a period:

```
set -- *;[ -e "$1" ]&&echo "$#"
```

The command above does however include files whose name starts with a period when an option like `dotglob` in bash or `glob_dots` in zsh is set. When `*` matches no file, the command results in an error in zsh with the default settings.

Comment: From your answer, I put this together for Bash: `(unset IFS; shopt -s dotglob nullglob; shopt -u failglob; a=(*); echo ${#a[@]})` - Note the parens, which cause execution in a subshell, thus preserving the current shell's options and IFS value.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can have more control on this using `find`:

```
find <path> -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "." | wc -c
```

- `find -maxdepth 1` will not go deeper into the hierarchy of files.
- `-type f` allows filtering to just files. Similarly, you can use `-type d` for directories.
- `-printf "."` prints a dot for every match.
- `wc -c` counts the characters, so it counts the dots created by the `print`... which means counting how many files exist in the given path.

Answer (score 2):

I used this command..works like a charm..only to change the maxdepth..that is sub directories

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec sh -c "echo -n {} ' ' ; ls -lR {} | wc -l" \;
```

Answer (score 2):

For the number of all file in a current directory try this:

```
ls -lR * | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no better alternative. This information might be off-topic to this question and you may already know this that under Linux (in general under Unix) directories are just special file which contains the list of other files (I understand that the exact details will be dependent on specific file system but this is the general idea). And there is no call to find the total number of entries without traversing the whole list. Please make me correct if I'm wrong.

Answer (score -1):

use ls -1 | wc -l

Comment: ls -l will give you an extra line of total number of blocks which will be an additional line while counting . ls -1 doesnt.

Comment: @VenkatarameshKommoju, a) you are not explaining why this is supposed to be better than `ls | wc -l` and b) it's not.