# Finding open file descriptors for a process linux ( C code )?

Tags: c, linux, process, file-descriptor

I wanted to find all fds opened for a process in linux.

Can I do it with glib library functions ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since you're on Linux, you've (almost certainly) got the `/proc` filesystem mounted. That means that the easiest method is going to be to get a list of the contents of `/proc/self/fd`; each file in there is named after a FD. (Use `g_dir_open`, `g_dir_read_name` and `g_dir_close` to do the listing, of course.)

Getting the information otherwise is moderately awkward (there's no helpful POSIX API for example; this is an area that wasn't standardized).

Comment: To list them for another process, list the directory `/proc/PID/fd` instead (where PID is the process id of the process in question). You'll only be able to see them for some processes if you're not root.

Comment: Using /proc/*/pid is of course very linux specific and not at all portable, but if that isn't a problem then it should work fine.

Comment: @Tom: The question _was_ tagged with `linux`…

Comment: There is one small pitfall to what out for: the `/proc/self/fd` directory itself also counts as an open file descriptor while scanning it.

Comment: @C2H5OH Yes. But the alternatives are horrific or just as problematic (e.g., running a subprocess to do the probing will open *more* FDs).

Comment: downvoted because frequently I've got access denied for processes started by own hands.

Comment: @ayvango That might be for setuid processes? You're very limited in what you can find out about those; processes running as different users are typically carefully walled off from each other. This is a deliberate security policy.

Answer (score 34):

Here's some code I used to use, I didn't know about /proc/self (thx Donal!), but this way is probably more generic anyway.   I've included the required includes for all the functions at the top.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

#ifndef FALSE
#define FALSE (0)
#endif
#ifndef TRUE
#define TRUE (!FALSE)
#endif

/* implementation of Donal Fellows method */ 
int get_num_fds()
{
     int fd_count;
     char buf[64];
     struct dirent *dp;

     snprintf(buf, 64, "/proc/%i/fd/", getpid());

     fd_count = 0;
     DIR *dir = opendir(buf);
     while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
          fd_count++;
     }
     closedir(dir);
     return fd_count;
}
```

I went through a very bad problem with leaking file handles once, and it turns out I actually coded the solution Tom H. suggested:

```
/* check whether a file-descriptor is valid */
int pth_util_fd_valid(int fd)
{
     if (fd < 3 || fd >= FD_SETSIZE)
          return FALSE;
     if (fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) == -1 && errno == EBADF)
          return FALSE;
     return TRUE;
}

/* check first 1024 (usual size of FD_SESIZE) file handles */
int test_fds()
{
     int i;
     int fd_dup;
     char errst[64];
     for (i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++) {
          *errst = 0;
          fd_dup = dup(i);
          if (fd_dup == -1) {
                strcpy(errst, strerror(errno));
                // EBADF  oldfd isnâ€™t an open file descriptor, or newfd is out of the allowed range for file descriptors.
                // EBUSY  (Linux only) This may be returned by dup2() during a race condition with open(2) and dup().
                // EINTR  The dup2() call was interrupted by a signal; see signal(7).
                // EMFILE The process already has the maximum number of file descriptors open and tried to open a new one.
          } else {
                close(fd_dup);
                strcpy(errst, "dup() ok");
          }
          printf("%4i: %5i %24s %s\n", i, fcntl(i, F_GETOWN), fd_info(i), errst);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

You'll probably want these too, to satisfy the last printf above...

```
char *fcntl_flags(int flags)
{
    static char output[128];
    *output = 0;

    if (flags & O_RDONLY)
        strcat(output, "O_RDONLY ");
    if (flags & O_WRONLY)
        strcat(output, "O_WRONLY ");
    if (flags & O_RDWR)
        strcat(output, "O_RDWR ");
    if (flags & O_CREAT)
        strcat(output, "O_CREAT ");
    if (flags & O_EXCL)
        strcat(output, "O_EXCL ");
    if (flags & O_NOCTTY)
        strcat(output, "O_NOCTTY ");
    if (flags & O_TRUNC)
        strcat(output, "O_TRUNC ");
    if (flags & O_APPEND)
        strcat(output, "O_APPEND ");
    if (flags & O_NONBLOCK)
        strcat(output, "O_NONBLOCK ");
    if (flags & O_SYNC)
        strcat(output, "O_SYNC ");
    if (flags & O_ASYNC)
        strcat(output, "O_ASYNC ");

    return output;
}

char *fd_info(int fd)
{
    if (fd < 0 || fd >= FD_SETSIZE)
        return FALSE;
    // if (fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) == -1 && errno == EBADF)
    int rv = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
    return (rv == -1) ? strerror(errno) : fcntl_flags(rv);
}
```

FD_SETSIZE is usually 1024, and the maximum files per process is usually 1024.  If you want to be sure, you can replace it with a call to this function, as described by TomH.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

rlim_t get_rlimit_files()
{
    struct rlimit rlim;
    getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rlim);
    return rlim.rlim_cur;
}
```

If you put all of that together into a single file (which I did, just to check it), you can produce an output similar to this to confirm it works as advertised:

```
0:     0                  O_RDWR  dup() ok
1:     0                O_WRONLY  dup() ok
2:     0                  O_RDWR  dup() ok
3:     0              O_NONBLOCK  dup() ok
4:     0     O_WRONLY O_NONBLOCK  dup() ok
5:    -1      Bad file descriptor Bad file descriptor
6:    -1      Bad file descriptor Bad file descriptor
7:    -1      Bad file descriptor Bad file descriptor
8:    -1      Bad file descriptor Bad file descriptor
9:    -1      Bad file descriptor Bad file descriptor
```

I hope that answers any questions you have, and in case you were wondering, I actually came here looking for the answer to the question the OP asked, and upon reading the answered, remember I had already written the code years ago.   Enjoy.

Comment: Note that pth_util_fd_valid will not work with holes in the fd table. Consider the following case:
`int fd = open(...); // fd =3`
`fd = open(...); // fd=4`
`close(4)`
The function will not reach fd=4

Comment: @kfir – pth_util_fd_valid only reports the validity of a given file handle, it does not contain a loop.

Comment: Second code example needs to include sys/select.h to define FD_SETSIZE.

Comment: It would be easier to scan `/proc/self/fd` or the slightly more portable `/dev/fd` than to assemble a path name based on the current process ID.

Answer (score 7):

If you can identify the process via pid you can simply do

```
ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd | wc - l
```

In C you can pipe everything and reuse either the output or you may count the files by yourself in the above mentioned directory(count method e.g. here [Counting the number of files in a directory using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121383/counting-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c))

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes C++ is an option, Donal's solution using boost::filesystem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <unistd.h>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
    std::string path = "/proc/" + std::to_string(::getpid()) + "/fd/";
    unsigned count = std::distance(fs::directory_iterator(path),
                                   fs::directory_iterator());
    std::cout << "Number of opened FDs: " << count << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: OP programs in C, not C++. This answer is irrelevant.

Comment: It would be easier to scan `/proc/self/fd` or the slightly more portable `/dev/fd` than to assemble a path name based on the current process ID.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean how can you do it programatically from within the process then the normal (if slightly horrid) method is to do something like looping over all possible descriptors (use `getrlimit()` to read `RLIMIT_NOFILE` to find the range) calling something like `fcntl(fd, F_GETFD, 0)` on each one and checking for EBADF responses to see which ones are not open.

If you mean that you want to find out from the shell what files a process has open then `lsof -p <pid>` is what you want.

Comment: I see a fair number of processes that have open FDs 0, 1, 2 and 255. Getting 252 failing syscalls would not be nice…

Comment: It all depends - obviously you don't want to do it in a performance critical piece of code but other than that it's not a big problem. The limit is more likely to be something like 2048 on a modern linux system anyway.

Comment: RLIMIT_NOFILE only tells you the maximum for newly created file descriptors, not the limit on currently open file descriptors, so you cannot use getrlimit to discover an upper bound on file descriptor numbers.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to do this now as part of some sandboxing code.  I want to run some arbitrary setup code, then list all the open file handles and close them, and then use setrlimit to prevent any new file handles from being opened.

Answer (score 1):

fstat command lists all running processes of the system and their open descriptors furthermore it lists what type of descriptor it is (file, socket, pipe, etc) and tries to give a hint of what the descriptor is reading or writing on such as what filesystem and what inode number on that file system