# Is it possible to check if there is a handle associated with a file in case I didn't save it as variable before?

Tags: php, file, handle

Let's say I do `fopen('filename.ext', 'w');`, but I didn't store the handle. Next I need to delete that file. Is there a way to find that this file has a handle attached to it and next close that unnamed handle ?

Comment: No, so make sure you always assign the handle to a variable

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> Thanks to the reference-counting system introduced with PHP 4's Zend Engine, a resource 
>   with no more references to it is detected automatically, and it is freed by the garbage 
>   collector. For this reason, it is rarely necessary to free the memory manually.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can [list `/proc/self/fd/`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583158/finding-open-file-descriptors-for-a-process-linux-c-code) to get the handles and corresponding file names, but there's no platform-independent php function.

Instead of wildly closing handles, you should wrap the `fopen` calls in try .. finally blocks (php 5.3+):

```
$f = fopen('filename.ext', 'w');
if ($f !== false) {
  try {
     // Some code that may throw an exception
  } finally {
     fclose($f);
  }
}
```

Note that at least on POSIX systems, you can also just delete the file (name) while you're holding a handle to it.