# How to force delete a file

Tags: c++

I want to find a certain way to delete a file. Some files cannot be deleted in a simple way with remove commands. like malwares or opened files. Is there any command that can do force delete?

Comment: Short answer: natively and cross-platform wise, it'll be probably better a better idea to use something else other than C++.

Comment: You should look at the boost::filesystem library. It can delete files and has a reasonably straightforward interface.  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html. If you encounter a problem while trying, post what you have done and Stack Overflow can then help you.

Comment: I guess nobody asked what OS because there's only one with malware and a restriction on deleting open files, which helps it entrench.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, files that are currently open (including executable files that are held open by the OS as part of being executed, likewise for DLLs and drivers that are currently loaded) can not be deleted unless you close the file first (which in the case of the executable files is not possible without serious trickery and "deceiving the OS" [e.g. closing a file in a driver, where the file wasn't originally opened by that driver]).

The way most real applications (e.g. installers) solve this is to add the deleting of the files to something that runs at shutdown or startup, and then ask the user to reboot the machine. [This also applies to copying over old files with new ones, which is more commonly the case when installing software].

In Unix/Linux environments, as long as you have sufficient rights to delete the file, it can be deleted, but if the file is open, it won't get "really deleted" until it is closed. This may not have a HUGE impact in most cases, but say for example some long-running program is producing a ginormous log-file, then you can't actually free the diskspace by deleting the file - it will only get freed once the file is closed. Restarting the long-running program is a solution, but if you have just calculated a large number of decimals of PI, and want to continue, it may not be a solution.

Both of these mechanisms are designed to prevent the OS from getting a sudden surprise when the file that it has open has suddenly gone missing - in particular when the OS may be using the file as a basis for reading/writing pages through the memory paging system (either memory mapped files or executable.

In short, there is no easy solution that GUARANTEES that any arbitrary file can be deleted.

Comment: I don't know how exactly, but in Windows, it _is_ possible to find out which process(es) have the file open.  Kill them, and you can then delete the file (although I think you have to wait a bit first).

Answer (score 1):

At first, you should determine fd of the given file: [Finding open file descriptors for a process linux ( C code )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583158/finding-open-file-descriptors-for-a-process-linux-c-code)

then close it.It's very better than force.