# How does the program access the inherited file descriptors?

Tags: c, linux, api

In Linux API,  a program inherits copies of file descriptors opened in its caller.

How does the program access the inherited file descriptors? Which functions are used for that purpose?

The caller of the program can be

- another program in C, or
- a bash shell. In this case, how can a program access the file descriptors opened in the shell which invokes it? From Bash Manual, in a bash shell,

  > When a simple command other than a builtin or shell function is to be executed, it is invoked in a separate execution environment that consists of the following. Unless otherwise noted, the values are inherited from the shell.
  >
  > - **the shell’s open files**, plus any modifications and additions specified by redirections to the command

Thanks.

Comment: Define "its caller". That sounds like too vague a term to me.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you talking about `fork()`?

Comment: its caller can be another C program or a bash shell.

Comment: You have to find an answer to this in your own code. Just passing the numbers in `argv[]` comes to mind, for example.

Comment: @NikosC. `fork()` create a child process of the current process. Then how can the child process access the file descriptors inherited from the current process

Comment: Uhm, by just doing it? Your question is either *unclear* (if you're just talking about `fork()`, because your program should **know** its open file descriptors) **or** *too broad* (if you're talking about e.g. the `exec*()` functions: you have to come up with your own solution how to pass fd numbers to the new binary).

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thanks. Could you point me to some code examples of the cases mentioned in your comment? Also if a program is started from bash, how can it access the file descriptors opened in the bash process?

Comment: @Tim: Could you instead add some code demonstration what you're trying to do? If you just `fork()`, you can use your POSIX file descriptor (of type `int`) in your child code just the same as in the parent.

Comment: @Tim finding open file descriptors yourself (without being told by the program calling you) is not a normal usecase. Still, there's a [question about it you can refer to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583158/finding-open-file-descriptors-for-a-process-linux-c-code)

Comment: @Felix: is it correct that child process get copies of file descriptors no the exact same file descriptors from its parent?

Comment: @Tim they are *copies* (so you can e.g. `close()` them independently in the parent and child), but have the same numerical value, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: bash **is** a C program.

Answer (score 4):

When you `fork()` a new process, your file descriptors are still valid. You access them as usual:

```
int fd = open(/* ... */);
pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid == 0) {
    // We're the child.
} else if (pid > 0) {
    // We're the parent.
} else {
    // fork() failed.
}
```

Both the parent and the child process can still access `fd`. There's nothing special required for the child process; it can access `fd` normally.

For the case where the child process is an different program, then the parent will need to communicate file descriptors to the child. Even if there is a way to find out all open file descriptors, it's impossible to tell what these descriptors refer to. Are they from the shell? From the program? It's just random data.

So you'd need to communicate them through a pipe or through `main()`'s arguments, or through an [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) mechanism. In other words, there's nothing special about file descriptors; they're data that needs to be communicated like any other data.

For example, a bash script might open some files, using 3 and 4 as file descriptors, and then tell your program which descriptors it uses:

```
#! /bin/bash

exec 3<> /tmp/newfile1
echo "This is file one." >&3

exec 4<> /tmp/newfile2
echo "This is file two." >&4

./myprogram 3 4
```

Your program can get these with:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    fd1 = atoi(argv[1]);
    fd2 = atoi(argv[2]);

    // ... Obviously you'd need error-checking, but this is just an example.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What if the caller of the child process is a bash shell process? That is the program of the child process is started from a bash shell.

Comment: Thanks again for the update. Could you give some examples of using pipe and using main's arguments to communicate open file descriptors from bash shell to a program in C?

Comment: @Tim I thought it would be self-explanatory, but I added an example.

Comment: I see. Thanks. How would you use pipe to do that instead?

Comment: @Tim Google "how to create a pipe in C" and "how to create a pipe in bash". In both cases, you use `mkfifo`.