# Counting the number of files in a directory in C using dirent not working a second time.

Tags: c, file, struct, dirent.h

```
 DIR *ptr;  
    struct dirent *ent, ent2;
    int n=0, i=0;
    dir = ".";

    ptr = opendir(dir);
    while((ent = readdir(ptr)) != NULL) 
        { 
            if(ent -> d_type != DT_DIR)
            { 
                n++;
            }       
        }   

    char array[n][100];

    while((ent2 = readdir(ptr)) != NULL) 
        { 
            if(ent2 -> d_type != DT_DIR)
            { 
                strcpy(array[i], ent2 -> d_name);      
                i++;
            }       
        }
```

In the above C code I tried to count the number of files excluding folders in the working directory. Then use the count to declare a double char array which is then used to store the file names. 
I need to declare the double array knowing the number of files.(not allowed declare a large array). The code works fine when I declare the double array with a large size and a just copy the file names to it without any counting. 
As I understand, the variable ent is changed within the first while loop. That's the reason I used a different "struct dirent ent2".

Comment: `readdir(ptr)` _If  the  end  of  the directory stream is reached, NULL is returned_

Comment: [Counting the number of files in a directory using C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1121383/608639).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem isn't the use of the same variable to store the result of `readdir` - that's perfectly fine.

Your issue is that `readdir` advances the position of the `DIR *` you're using each time you call it. Once you've seen all the files, that directory pointer can't be advanced any more. It doesn't loop back to the beginning.

You can use [`rewinddir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rewinddir.html) to reset it to the first entry in the directory. (Or close it and reopen it.)