# Counting number of files and folders in directory

Tags: c, file-io, directory

How can I count the number of files and folders in a directory using C. I have no clue. I couldn't write single line code.
I do not care about current directory . and the parent directory.. 
I have to give a pathname for example “C:/Users/me/Documents/Example” while I'm running the program.

And I need a output like " There are 2 folders and 4 files in this directory".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Look at the man pages for `opendir`, `readdir`, and `closedir`.  Although they might not be available on Windows.

Comment: And there must be several thousands of examples on how to enumerate directories and files on Windows, both using the POSIX compatibility functions already mentioned by @TomKarzes, but also using native Windows API functions. Just use your favorite search engine and you should find them.

Comment: On Windows, use the functions `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile`.

Answer (score 0):

### for linux os

The code below shall list all files and sub-directories in `dir_path` (for current directory use `dir_path = "."`).

**DESCRIPTION**

This description qouted from man7.org [link](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html)

```
struct dirent *readdir(DIR *dirp);
```

#### readdir()

The `readdir()` function returns a pointer to a `dirent structure`
representing the next directory entry in the directory stream pointed
to by `dirp`.  It returns `NULL` on reaching the **end of the directory**
stream or if an **error occurred**. for further details go to the link above for **man7.org**.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <dirent.h> 

int main(void) 
{ 
   /* de is Pointer for directory entry */
    struct dirent *de;  
    const char* dir_path = "C:/Users/me/Documents/Example";
    /*opendir() returns a pointer of DIR type.*/  
    DIR *dr = opendir(dir_path); 

    if (dr == NULL)  /* opendir returns NULL if couldn't open directory */
    { 
        printf("Could not open current directory" ); 
        return 0; 
    } 

    while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL){
        printf("%s\n", de->d_name); 
    }
    closedir(dr);     
    return 0; 
}
```

### for windows os

for windows use the header file: `fileapi.h` see microsoft docs here: [fileapi.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/)

this question answered before in SO in the link below using the `FindFirstFile`, `FindNextFile` and `FindClose` functions.

please review the answer in the link: [list directory in windows in C programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314542/listing-directory-contents-using-c-and-windows)

Comment: I checked everything you sent. And Probably everything on here.I found an answer in the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121383/counting-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c  a program on the answer count everything. I wanna seperate them like  files and folders.  These are so complicated for me I'm kind of beginner on programming. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I also found a link https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Testing-File-Type.html.

Can I use S_ISDIR and S_ISREG macros while I separate regular files and folders?

Anyone wanna show me? I Really need help Once a time Feed Me  please Dont Teach me how to fish.