# Count Files in directory and subdirectory in Linux using C

Tags: c, linux, file, ansi-c

I am trying to count files of a directory and its subdirectories. But I am getting a seg fault every time and I don't see why.

I used the code from here:
[Counting the number of files in a directory using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121383/counting-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c)

Thanks for help

```
#include <stdio.h>   // use input/output functions
#include <string.h>  // use string functions
#include <dirent.h>  // use directory functions

int countFilesRec(char* dirName);

// Global variable
int countFiles = 0;

/** Count files and subdirectories in given directory. */
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Read parameters
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: countFiles <directory>\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Count Files
    printf(countFilesRec(argv[1]));

    return 0;
}

   
int countFilesRec(char *path) {
    DIR *dir_ptr = NULL;
    struct dirent *direntp;
    char *npath;
    if (!path) return 0;
    if( (dir_ptr = opendir(path)) == NULL ) return 0;

    int count=0;
    while( (direntp = readdir(dir_ptr)))
    {
        if (strcmp(direntp->d_name,".")==0 ||
            strcmp(direntp->d_name,"..")==0) continue;
        switch (direntp->d_type) {
            case DT_REG:
                ++count;

                                if (strcmp(direntp->d_name,"arbeitspfad bsks.txt")==0){
                                    count=count-1;
                                    count=count+1;
                                }

                                //printf("%s\n",direntp->d_name);
                break;
            case DT_DIR:
                npath=malloc(strlen(path)+strlen(direntp->d_name)+2);
                sprintf(npath,"%s/%s",path, direntp->d_name);
                                //printf("%s\n",npath);
                count += countFilesRec(npath);
                free(npath);
                break;
        }
    }
    closedir(dir_ptr);
        //printf(count);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Productivity tip: enable all warnings to quickly see problems like `printf(countFilesRec(argv[1]));`.  Maybe as "warning: passing argument 1 of 'printf' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` does not take an integer. It takes a format string and a variable list of arguments. Your problem can probably be fixed by changing:

```c
    // Count Files
    printf(countFilesRec(argv[1]));
```

to

```c
   int fileCount = countFilesRec(argv[1]);
   printf("File count = %d\n", fileCount);
```

The change stores the integer result of your function in a variable and then uses a suitable format string to print it.